# Failed to execute goal... error. Deploying to Heroku

Tags: spring, spring-boot, heroku

I am trying to deploy my application to Heroku, but I'm geting this message all the time. When I run it in IntelliJ the application is working.
The application is written in Spring Boot.

What could be the cause of this error?

[image: Error I recive when I try to push to Heroku]

Here is my pom.xml

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: you have a build failure in your code

Comment: The code builds correctly on my machine, it only breaks when I try to push it to Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is due to a mismatch of the Java version in your project's pom.xml file and that being used by Heroku.

A simple solution could be either specify your target version in pom.xml or configure the Java version in Heroku. You can add the following code below `<description>` in your pom.xml file to specify your target version.

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
```

Comment: I tried puting version 1.8, and 11, but still I get the same error.